# Google Maps Sidebar Undefined Variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to display deviceid variable in sidebar,

I am able to pull in data and display the locations on my map just fine ... but the sidebar is displaying undefined.
i'm new to javascript though so could be wrong though.

Where is error ?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var deviceid;
    var point;
        var map;
    var image = 'images/mm_20_red.png';
    var url = "phpsqlajax_genxml3.php";

    function load() {
        var milan = new google.maps.LatLng(45.4636889, 9.1881408);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: milan,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions );

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      GDownloadUrl(url, function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var deviceid = markers[i].getAttribute("deviceid");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")));
          var timestamp = markers[i].getAttribute("timestamp");   
          var html = "<b>" + deviceid;

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            deviceid: deviceid,
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: image
          });

            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

            //Creates a sidebar button for the marker
            createMarkerButton(marker);

                // START zoom
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                map.setZoom(16);
                });
                // END zoom
        }
      });

    }


    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function GDownloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        } 
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function createMarkerButton(marker) {
  var ul = document.getElementById("marker_list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var deviceid = marker.getTitle();
  //li.innerHTML = title;
  li.innerHTML = deviceid;
  ul.appendChild(li);

  //Trigger a click event to marker when the button is clicked.
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(li, "click", function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "click");
  });
}   

    function doNothing() {}

</script>
```

Comment: -1, this is not a "plz debug my code" site

Comment: i understand, this is not place for debug my code. any reference will help me :)

Comment: install firebug plugin for Firefox and debug. Or better, first make a good code review.

Comment: Firebug for Firefox helped me much ... :)

Comment: JSLint.com is a useful site for identifying errors in your Javascript.